# What's the best way to include custom HTML in a Symfony form?

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm working with a Symfony generated admin and need to include some custom HTML into a form. This HTML (a label, img tag, and link) should only appear when the action is 'edit'. What's the best way to do this? It seems like I should just be able to include a partial, but I don't know where to include it from. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:
I created a partial and set it to display within the moduel's generator.yml file (in the 'edit' section)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the functionality you want the partial to have you could also write a custom widget and use your custom widget instead of the standard symfony one.
(I use this for a widget wich displays me various sizes of images after a file upload)